# Eliminate a directory in the URL and redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all instances of:

```
http://example.com/projects/title-of-project
```

To:

```
http://example.com/title-of-project
```

How would I do this?

**htaccess**

```
# WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where is your htaccess located ? In root folder or in `projects` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (in root folder)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /wordpress/

  RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Make sure *mod_rewrite* is **enabled** (and `htaccess` files allowed)

Comment: It's not working for some reason. I posted my htaccess above. Are the previous rules interfering?

Comment: Yes, they do. I edited my answer, taking your comment into consideration. You can replace your current entire code by the one i gave you

Comment: Looks like it's working now. Just have one issue. I'm working on my local machine and now the posts go to `localhost/title-of-post` (as they should). But would it be possible to keep the base of the WordPress installation intact so instead of `localhost/title-of-post`, it reads `localhost/wordpress/title-of-post` instead?

Comment: Sure. You can use edited code instead. Maybe you'll have to clear your browser's cache (since old 301 rule may be in there)

Comment: Now it's going back to the old structure with `projects`. I cleared the cache too. Does it take some time?

Comment: Well, reading your comment back again, i think i didn't understand what you wanted. Could you explain it one more time with an example ?